# SignalR server ping error

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I use SignalR 2.0.0 Win2012 iis8 
After using latest 2.0.0 version in previous version the error not occurred. i am received that error: "Failed to ping server". but i am still connected.
why i receive the above error? 
what i need to do for resolve the problem?
Thanks

Comment: Could you provide us with more information on your setup? Such as your hubs, jscript etc.

Answer (score 0):

my part code of client:

```
function connect(host)
   {

  var hubConnection = $.hubConnection.('');

  hubConnection.url = host;

 hubConnection.start()
           .done(open)
           .fail(error);
}
function open()
{
 console.log('success')
}
function disconnect()
{
var self = this,
 hubConnection = $.hubConnection("");
 console.log('disconnect ')
 hubConnection.stop(true, true);
}
function error(error)
{
 console.log('error')
}
```

if you need more details for answer do not hesitate to ask.